# CSS and HTML overlapping images creates negative space.. How do I remove the neg space?

Tags: html, css

I have created a [website](http://www.unemploymentstudios.tk/CellStream.html)...  and I have overlapped two images twice.  I now have negative space on the website between the last image and the Footer.  How can I remove it from the site without scrapping the overlapping images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use `position:relative` on image from `<div class="ontent box">`. Read [this article](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/css-xhtml/understanding-css-positioning-part-1/) to understand why (position part).
Use container with background image and video inside- http://jsfiddle.net/fliptheweb/y4Djx/

Comment: Just wanted to say Thank You @fliptheweb and everyone else for your help...  I followed your advice and I got it looking better.  It still has negative space, but it looks better than before.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your document as xhtml strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

and have 49 errors and one warning. I suggest [validating](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.unemploymentstudios.tk/CellStream.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) your file, fixing the errors and then seeing if that solves the problem, if not ask again :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're using relative positions for so many of the elements. This doesn't remove them from the flow of the page so the space that they would ocupy is still reserved for them.

To fix it, create a div to contain each set of overlapping images, and position the div relatively but don't change it's top: or bottom: values. Then absolutely position the overlapping images inside that div.